# Number of Active Users

Tags: support

Is there any way we can tell how many users have been active on Worldbuilding over a period of time, like, say the past 5 minutes/hour/day?

Comment: You can see some public data at [Quantcast](https://www.quantcast.com/worldbuilding.stackexchange.com) (no I don't know how they measure some of that), and you could probably write SEDE queries to tease out some of this (at the per-day or per-week level).  The SEDE data is updated weekly, so that won't give you up-to-the-minute information but you can write SQL queries against slightly-older data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to the question as asked is: Not directly.

That said...

## The site is currently doing *very well* in terms of activity.

Diamond moderators have access to "analytics" data, which includes data like number of visits on the site per day. (The data is available down to a resolution of one day, so doesn't really meet your request of being for minutes or hours.) The specifics of analytics data cannot be shared in public.

However, having gone in and looked at some of it just now, I *can* state as much as that by almost any reasonable measure of site activity (number of visits, number of questions and answers, number of votes cast, number of edits, ...) we are currently **at or close to all time highs.** This includes the initial surge of activity at the beginning of the public beta period, which we have actually in some ways *surpassed*. Good job, community!

Comment: I can see the little sidebar that links to Area 51. Is that what we're talking about?

Comment: @SerbanTanasa No, analytics is separate from Area 51 and is available to diamond moderators only.

Comment: The Area 51 stats are similar but less detailed (i.e. they just seem to be a 2 week average while we can see the daily figures)